# The Value set in ThreadLocal for Spring JMX works inconsistently

Tags: spring, spring-boot, concurrency, thread-local, spring-jmx

The Value set in ThreadLocal for Spring JMX works inconsistently

```
@ManagedResource(objectName = "MAN-TEST:name=SetValue", description = "Set Value for JMX")
@Component
public class ValueSetJMX {
    private static ThreadLocal<String> jmxValue = new ThreadLocal<String>();

    @ManagedAttribute
    public void setManValue(String valueJMX) {
    jmxValue.set(valueJMX)
    }

    @ManagedAttribute
    public String getManValue() {
            return jmxValue.get();
    }
}
```

After setting a value for setManValue , if I invoke getManValue() multiple times, the result will be sometimes null.

Is there any better way to resolve this

Answer (score 2):

I presume you mean setting/getting the value remotely.

No; you can't use a `ThreadLocal` for that - there is no guarantee the same RMI thread will be used for each request.

Comment: getManValue() is used in all JMX operations (a global value set using aspect) If two Users operates these beans and set two different values, then it's a problem, How concurrency can be attained for this.

Comment: JMX operations are discrete; you can't store state between calls without adding user code (and accessing the state based on some input data). A `ThreadLocal` just won't cut it.